# Are full links when linking resources worse than paths?

Tags: html

The question is very simple and even tho I might get downvoted into oblivion for it, I can't find a good search query for this.

If I link images, stylesheets, scripts and other things with the full website url (http://url.tld/css/style.css) instead of path (css/style.css) , are the visitors affected negatively? Is there any difference?

The html page is on the same link as the resource, so we're not talking about external resources.

Comment: The performance of the request should not be different. The biggest issue with full URLs is that if you ever want to host on another domain (or context), everything will break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only makes a difference if you change your domain name. You cannot simply transfer the scripts over but have to change each line or the include of those files then.

One small thing to keep in mind: Your string will be longer and so your file will be a very bit bigger in size but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: alright, but considering that the website is strongly linked to the domain (images, logos and whatnot) and notepad++ can just replace all the links, it's not an issue. What I care about is if it affects page load time or performance.

Comment: No, it won't affect it negative.

Comment: Alright, I will accept this as the answer as soon as I can

Comment: Ah I got a small impact I can think of: You have to send more bytes because it is a longer string then ;). But that doesn't matter much.

Comment: As in the overall size of the html page? That's a very tiny impact, I was thinking about crazy things like domain lookups for every res

Comment: No, nothing like that may occur. You are fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

Either won't affect visitors. Specifying the protocol might cause problems in the future if your users can switch between `http` and `https`. Specifying the folder also means changes when you move the site. So best to use relative

Comment: I don't want to make another question for this, even tho I should. I'm only doing this because I have a page, address.tld , and I've now created another page that's the english version of the main one, found at en.address.tld . It points to the /en/ folder located in the root of the website. I wanted to only copy the index.php and not every single resource, and even tho adding ../ worked when accessing address.tld/en , it didn't when accessing en.address.tld. This is the only solution I could think of, specifying full address in index.php